# Unzip a sequence of case classes with two fields

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let's say I have a case class `MyCaseClass` with two fields in the constructor, and a sequence of values of this case class, `sequence`.

How do I unzip `sequence`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fields are `a` and `b` then I'd just write

```
(sequence map (_.a), sequence map (_.b))
```

OK, you traverse `sequence` twice, but list traversal is so cheap, I'd wager that this is quicker than using Option.get.

edit: After Rex's comment, couldn't resist running a benchmark myself; results below...

```
times in ms for 100 traversals of 10000 elem collection, 
   L = List, A = Array, V = Vector
                                               // Java 6           // Java 7
sequence.unzip{case MyCaseClass(a,b) => (a,b)} //L 173 A 101 V 87  //L 27 A 29 V 21
sequence.unzip{MyCaseClass.unapply(_).get}     //L 194 A 116 V 100 //L 35 A 32 V 25
(sequence map (_.a), sequence map (_.b))       //L 177 A 70  V 86  //L 34 A 20 V 23
```

Your results may vary, according to CPU, memory, JRE version, collection size, phase of the moon etc.

Comment: Cheap? It depends on how long `sequence` is.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge I agree, cheap(er).  For sequence.length = N, you're looking at 2N vs N*(cost of creating new tuple).  My bet is that cost of creating tuple is substantially higher than "2" for a sequence (List or Vector impl).

Comment: @Robin Not really, you need to think in terms of time per element. Traversal is just dereferencing the `tail` variable, which is dwarfed by whatever you're doing with each element.

Comment: It really depends on the collection.  Arrays are happy to be mapped and are grumpy about being zipped, so this version is considerably better for arrays (~3x in my hands for simple things).  In contrast, `Vector` has no particular preference for being mapped vs. unzipped, and turns in better performance with `unapply(_).get`.  `List` is pretty close both ways.  Etc..

Comment: @Rex Tried it myself; results above if you're interested

Comment: @LuigiPlinge - This is a particularly tricky one to benchmark due to heavy memory usage and finicky inlining.  Note that the increased times on the `unapply(_).get` are the result of not warming up much; once fully optimized they end up essentially the same in everything I've tried (multiple collections, multiple JVMs).  Sometimes the not-very-warm case can be important, but usually it's not.  Also, 7 vs 6 are almost identical in my hands (with plenty of warm up), so I presume it's a consequence of changed JIT compilation thresholds or somesuch.

Answer (score 3):

Case classes don't extend Product2, Product3 etc., so a simple unzip doesn't work.

This does:

```
sequence.unzip { MyCaseClass.unapply(_).get }
```

Comment: Upon testing, this is just as fast as explicit pattern-matching.  I will just leave a note here that `sequence.unzip { case MyCaseClass(a,b) => (a,b) }` is equivalent for anyone who prefers that syntax.